# Sort Collection by decorating a property with an attribute. (collection retrieval is triggered through reflection)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, collections, sql-order-by

I have an object which contains an `ICollection`:

```
public abstract class Container : Component, IContainer
{        
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Since it is virtual, the `Component`s will be lazy loaded (when 'getting' the `Component`s property: `myContainerInstance.Components`).

Our application is heavily relying on reflection. One of the reflection parts is retrieving all properties of a certain Container, loops through it and retrieves the value of each property. Something like this:

```
var props = type.GetProps();
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var propValue = prop.GetValue(bo, null); // EF triggers lazy loading in case the prop is a virtual ICollection and immediately _materializes_ all the data
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am trying to find a way how to have EF retrieve that data *with* an order by specified. Is that somehow possible? I was trying to google if maybe it's possible to decorate that collection property with an attribute that would instruct EF to order the date its retrieving. Or I'm too tired to find the good google query, or it's not possible, or ...?

PS: disabling lazy loading for that property is not an option, since certain `Component`s in that collection are `Container`s on its own. This causes humongous select statements. The whole object structure can theoretically contain an infinite depth (reality is - for now - up to 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know it is not possible.

In ObjectContext API it is possible with explicit loading by creating query from navigation property but lazy loading must be turned off because once lazy loading is enabled any access to collection property immediately triggers loading so the explicit loading will load data again. DbContext API should be able to use explicit loading even if lazy loading is turned on. Still explicit loading means that you must call some method / query manually to load the property.

Comment: There has to be a hack around this! Maybe clearing the collection and filling it again with a correctly sorted list of the same dynamic proxy objects EF gave us could work? Will give this a shot tomorrow.. It's kinda sleeping time here :)

Comment: I was able to work around it.. see my answer.
I did mark yours as correct, since "not possible" is a correct answer on my question :)
My answer is just in case someone would bump into the same issue.

Comment: :) I had to switch to something else for a while.. it's there now

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in the end (simplified version):

```
var propValue = prop.GetValue(bo, null); // this (in case the `prop` is a virtual `ICollection<Component>`) lazy loads all components, returning them not always in the same order (due to paralelism on sql server?))
if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
{
    ...
    if (prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
    {
        ...        
    }
    else if (innerType.IsSubclassOfOrEquivalentTo(typeof(Component)) && propValue != null)
    {
        // order the list of components in memory into a new variable
        var listOfComponents = ((IEnumerable) propValue).Cast<Component>().OrderBy(c => c.ComponentId);            

        dynamic componentsHash = propValue; // I had to use dynamic, because sometimes the propValue was an List<...>, sometimes a HashSet<...>, sometimes a ...
        componentsHash.Clear(); // empty the collection retrieved by EF

        int componentCount = listOfComponents.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < componentCount; i++)
        {
            var component = listOfComponents[i];
            componentsHash.Add(component); // re-add components to the collection
            ...
        }
        // at this point the collection object contains ordered dynamic proxy objects (attached EF objects)
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
...
```